# window.open not working/not gets called

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I have a button in my form, which generates PDF files and saves in the local machine; now after saving them in local machien by clicking the button I want to see the files in the browser for download too(which more than one files)  ;

My attempted code is as following:

```
<form name="frm1" id="frm1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         .
         .
         .
  <button type="submit" name="btnCreatePDF_8" class="btn btn-primary" onclick= "newDoc();"> Export to PDF </button>
</form>


<script>
       function newDoc()
       {
           window.open("http://localhost/MyProject/1234_1_8.pdf")
       }
</script>
```

It creates the PDFs but I cannot get my javascript function (newDoc()) work!

Your help is appreciated! Also if you need more clarification, please let me know which part I have to provide more clarification.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Do not use a submit button. That is your problem, it is submitting the form and also calling the function. Looks like the form submission is winning the race. Change it to a regular button.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <button name="btnCreatePDF_8" class="btn btn-primary" onclick= "newDoc();"> Export to PDF </button> // remove the type="submit"
```